# Which approach for big community (large number of members) but in small groups (2-4) persons?

Tags: web-applications, community, community-management

Started asking this: [Another Question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29957/how-to-build-a-small-personal-like-community)

Thought that the idea of implementing this in a forum would be a good idea but its not.

I am desperately searching for ways to create (hopefully) a large community and have them create content(like posts with text attachements e.t.c), BUT i need them to work in groups of 2-4 people.

Forums are not a good idea for the simple reason that you would need to create thousands of forums and manually administer them.

For example lets assume that the community has 10.000 people in ~2.500  groups.

If each group demands for 2-3 subforums i will end up having ~7000 subforums to administer in any  board software.

Its easy to say "write your own" but that's what i want to avoid, at least for the beginning.

I would appreciate any ideas that you guys have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenAtrium](http://openatrium.com/) is based on Drupal and for free. The default organizational unit there is a group. It provides a blog and a notebook (wiki) and some features for each group. It took me about 1h to install and configure and I have seen some nice themes for it as well (but not yet tested).

Comment: I got to watch the introductory video and it seems very nice, but too much for what i need and more closed to extensive custom development that i want to do....I am fighting against the idea (that request a lot of time) to manually create my primary data repository from scratch...Primary data = people's posts

Comment: I don't understand what the actual problem is. Do you mean you have a lot of posts in an existing database which needs to be migrated? Then you can write a script to do the migration process for users and posts. What do you mean with `too much for what i need and more closed to extensive custom development that i want to do`?

Comment: yes you are right. NO i dont have existing data, only requirements for what i want to build. I need a blog that each user can have its own, or each group (of 2-4persons) can have its own, AND being able to custom develop apps on these entries and manipulate them...

Comment: Ok, then which of those requirements is not met by openatrium? What do you mean with `AND being able to custom develop apps on these entries and manipulate them`? What apps? The base for openatrium is a mysql database which you can easily access and modify. You can also develop plugins for drupal/openatrium or pick from existing ones.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. I would prefer for atrium to have some kind of api but thats not a requirement. In time i would need other functions like forum for example. As for the apps an example is a system where the user could download offline in various formats his content and keep it. Other apps include specialized functions regarding the general idea which i cannot reveil publicly until i release it...

Comment: I am also looking at commercial packages like the combination of invision power apps. IP.Board provide the basis and the api while ip.blog provides my main functionality (group and private blogs with tags e.t.c). And this on a common db,authentication .....

Comment: If I understand you right, which is rather difficult, you want to customize the software, which is also possible as it is drupal. MySQL is a very common db and of course openatrium supports authentication. By the way: maybe it is better to use (blog-)posts an a smart commenting system instead of a classic bulletin board module which may be a little too much for 2-4 users in one group.

Comment: exactly my friend this is what i came to beleive..choose somthing that its a blog nad gives the option for either a private blog or a group blog ,and being able to write code against a well formed db to do the rest....

Comment: i already have paid for a ip.board license and since io have been working for a while with invision, i will explore first the possibilities frmo them and then drupal and atrium...